# How do I combine two HTML levels?

Tags: javascript, html5, html

If I have two levels that I have made separate in HTML5 how may I combine them so one comes after another?.

Comment: What do you mean by “one comes after the other”? *After* in time, or in space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that they are in several .html files you can simply call

```
window.location = "level2.html"
```

when the player ends the first level.

Also: You should consider that if you are playing the game from a browser (not on a packaged app), many server requests will happen between the levels so it won't be an optimal user experience. If you are still learning is fine to do it the "crappy" way, but eventually you game will be big enough that this will be unbearable.

If you are using HTML5 canvas I would suggest placing two canvas on your HTML file and "swap" them (make the first one invisible and the second one visible, it is just some css). If you are planning to create many levels, I would suggest you to design your game so you can place everything in one .html file and use just one canvas, even if you keep different .js files.